# R lists: part of tag name

Tags: r

I just found out a strange behaviour when using lists in R:

```
> a$abc = 15
> a$abc
[1] 15
> a$ab
[1] 15
> a$a
NULL
> a$ab = NULL
> a$ab
[1] 15
```

Is it a feature or a bug? Is it possible to change this behaviour? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: a$a is NULL because you have another item in your list beginning with a. for example `list(abc=15,av=12)$a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R performs partial matching when using `$`, so you'll get back `abc` when passing `ab`. Probably the matching is not done for a single character. To assignment:

```
a$ab = NULL
```

simply does nothing, just check the object afterwards. A null object is added to the list, which in R means that nothing is added.

Comment: So it is a feature... Very misleading from my point of view. Thank you very much for clarification!

Comment: The partial matching is not a good feature in my view, and should only ever be used in interactive mode. If this answers your question, you can click on the green tick mark of the left of my answer. This signals to the rest of the community that this question has been answered, and gets me some reputation.

Comment: if you want to avoid partial matching, just use `[[` eg `a[["ab"]]`